# android cannot change attributes in overriden textview control

Tags: android, view, textview, overriding

I have created a control which extends textview. Unfortunately when I try any call any functions such as setText or setTextSize from my activity, nothing happens.

I managed to get around the theming issues by creating a constructor that accepts a standard textview and then creating the control with the following code:

```
    TextView l = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.dlgStarup_lblHeading);   
    myTextView lblHeading = new myTextView(l, _theme, _CONTROLTYPE.SUBTITLE);

    myTextView.setText("Any text can go here"); //this doesn't work
```

but not being able to set properties of the control after it's been created is causing a real problem

here is my myTextView class

```
public class myTextView extends TextView
{

    public enum _CONTROLTYPE
    {
        TITLE,SUBTITLE,MESSAGE,LABEL,LARGE_LABEL,ICON;
    }

    public myTextView(TextView _t, myTheme _theme, _CONTROLTYPE _controltype)
    {
        super(_t.getContext());
        this.setTheme(_t, _theme, _controltype);
    }

    public myTextView(Context _context, AttributeSet _attrs, int _defStyle) 
    {
        super(_context, _attrs, _defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public myTextView(Context _context, AttributeSet _attrs) 
    {
        super(_context, _attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private void setTheme(TextView _control, theme _theme, _CONTROLTYPE _controltype)
    {
        _control.setTextColor(_theme.colours.titleText);
        _control.setTextSize(_theme.fonts.getPointSize(myTheme._POINTSIZES.TITLE));
    }

           //this didn't work
    public void setThemeOld(theme _theme, _CONTROLTYPE _controltype)
    {
        //I tried calling both this.setText.... and super.setText..., neither changed the apperance of my control
        this.setTextColor(_theme.colours.titleText);
        this.setTextSize(_theme.fonts.getPointSize(myTheme._POINTSIZES.TITLE));

        //I also tried putting this here - it had no effect
        this.invalidate()
    }
}
```

(edit)
full code where the textviews are initilized, as requested:

```
protected Dialog_Startup(Context _context, boolean _cancelable, OnCancelListener _cancelListener, theme _theme) 
{
    super(_context, _cancelable, _cancelListener);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_startup);

    TextView l = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.dlgStarup_lblHeading);       
    myTextView lblHeading = new myTextView(l, _theme, _CONTROLTYPE.SUBTITLE);

    l = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.dlgStarup_lblProgress);
    myTextView lblMessage = new myTextView(l,_theme, _CONTROLTYPE.LABEL);
    lblMessage.setText("THIS ISN'T WORKING"); //this isn't workig

    Intent i = new Intent(_context, DataService.class);
    //_context.startService(i);

}
```

Comment: could post code from oncreate ?

Answer (score 0):

I think (until you post your code) the problem you were creating  new object from custom textview and not using your textview in xml layout  , try this code may help you

```
TextView l = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.dlgStarup_lblHeading);   
myTextView lblHeading = new myTextView(l, _theme, _CONTROLTYPE.SUBTITLE);
l.setText("Any text can go here");
```

Comment: yes, that would work... but it doesn't really solve the issue of WHY my overridden class is not working when functions are called on it

Comment: what do you mean with overridden class ??

Comment: sorry, extended class... myTextView